# xpath - How do I include all elements in an element in the output?

Tags: xml, xpath, oxygenxml

Is there any way to display the the whole `<desc>` in the output, including the text that is inside another element like `<name>` or `<bibl>`?
Also, I want both `<desc>` elements in the output. With `if //*[@xml:id='sooke']) then ('Description:', //*[@xml:id='sooke']/desc) else ('the place does not exist')`´ it works well but the text inside  is not included, neither is ,  or

```
   <place xml:id="sooke">

    <placeName>Sooke</placeName>

    <location>
      <geo>48.377315 -123.723832</geo>
    </location>

    <desc>In 1842, <name key="douglas_j">James Douglas</name> refers to Sooke as
      "Sy-yousung," and makes several entries about the geographical features of Sooke in
        <ref type="doc" cRef="V465HB02.scx">this despatch</ref>. In another spelling, with
      the addition of the letter "i," <name key="douglas_j">Douglas</name> refers to
      "Sy-yousuing" again in an <ref type="doc" cRef="V515HB02.scx">1849 despatch</ref>,
      wherein he states that it is "25 miles distant from <name type="place" key="victoria"
        >Fort Victoria</name>," and "has the important advantage of a good mill stream and a
      great abundance of fine timber."</desc>

    <desc>Another possible Sooke-landscape reference exists in the name "<ref
        type="external"
        target="http://bcgenesis.uvic.ca/getDoc.htm?id=V465HB02.scx&amp;search=whoyring#searchHit1"
        >Whoyring</ref>," present day <name type="place">Becher Bay</name>, which <name
        key="douglas_j">Douglas</name> refers to as a port, located eight miles east of
      "Sy-yousuing" (<bibl>G.P.V. Akrigg and H.B. Akrigg, <title level="m">British Columbia
          Chronicle, 1788-1846</title> (Victoria: Discovery Press, 1975),
      349</bibl>).</desc>

    <!-- <name type="place" key="sooke">Sooke</name> -->
  </place>
```

I've tried several variants of `if //*[@xml:id='sooke']) then ('Description:', //*[@xml:id='sooke']/desc) else ('the place does not exist')`´, including descendant-or-self::

Comment: 1) Where is `<place` tag closed? 2) do you want first `desc` tag content only - if so what is the unique locator for that node? Or the entire `place` node children nodes text?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is, if you select the `desc` element(s) then the complete node is selected, if you want all its text use `desc/string()`.